# Is it natural that $\overline{\int f}=\int\bar f$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Is it natural that $$\overline{\int f}=\int\bar f\ \ ?$$

I tried to prove it, but with no success.

Comment: What's your definition for the integral?

Comment: And what are you defining as $\overline X$? You need to be way more specific.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: It's the conjugate of $X$.

Comment: @quid: An integral is an integral ! I don't know if it helps, but $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$

Comment: @MSE: There are many kinds of integrals: Riemann, Lebesgue, Stieltjes, Daniell; over real or complex numbers; for functions, differential forms, real, complex, Grassmann numbers, etc. It would be hard to find one for which the given relation doesn't hold, but it should be an immediate consequence of the definitions. You're presumably asking about a Riemann or Lebesgue sum, but even then there would be a difference in the proof: The Riemann integral is ugly nonsense, while the construction of the Lebesgue integral is almost axiomatic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is common to define the integral of a complex valued function (on $\mathbb{R}^n$) via considering its real and imaginary part.

That is for $f = u + i v$ one defines $\int f = \int u + i \int v$ (and $f$ is integrable if both $u,v$ are integrable).

Then the question boils down to is $\int (-v) =  -\int v$, which is  a well-known property of the (real) integral.

Answer (score 3):

No an integral is not an integral ! Specificaly, the fact that $f$ is in $L^2$ gives you the information that $$\int f\bar g=:\left< f,g\right>,$$
is a scalar product, and thus that $$\overline{\int f}=\overline{\left<f,1\right>}=\left<1,f\right>=\int \bar f.$$